# If a HSM RNG is FIPS 140-2 compliant, does that imply FIPS 186-2 compliance also?

Tags: cryptography, fips, hsm

If the RNG of an HSM is said to be compliant to FIPS 140-2 (approved DRBG - SP 800-90 CTR mode) does also imply that it is compliant to FIPS 186-2?

Comment: If it did, then what would be the point of (those portions of) FIPS 186-2, as opposed to having just 140-2?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling can you elaborate your answer a bit more?

Comment: Did you notice the second sentence in a comment under the same question you posted on StackOverflow?

Comment: I did not answer the question.

Comment: Note: This question has been [cross-posted also to Cryptography SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/37362/1142).